# How do I redefine a Vector3 array in unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using an array of Vector3 coordinates which needs to be updated to new coordinates, based on a new anchor, on each refresh (see code below). However this code is incorrect and I can't find any clear solution to redefine the array. I am using a flexible-size array as some elements are deleted at other points in the code. Is there a better solution or a way to redefine the array? Thanks

```
public class Example : MonoBehavior {

public Vector3 anchorPoint;
Vector3[] locations;

// Various code

void OnRefresh() {
   locations = {
       new Vector3(anchorPoint.x + 1, anchorPoint.y, anchorPoint.z),
       new Vector3(anchorPoint.x - 1, anchorPoint.y, anchorPoint.z),
       new Vector3(anchorPoint.x, anchorPoint.y + 1, anchorPoint.z),
       new Vector3(anchorPoint.x, anchorPoint.y - 1, anchorPoint.z),
       new Vector3(anchorPoint.x, anchorPoint.y, anchorPoint.z + 1),
       new Vector3(anchorPoint.x, anchorPoint.y, anchorPoint.z - 1)
   };
}
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: VS is not happy with the use of {} and expects ; instead idk why @derHugo

Comment: you need `new []{ ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your syntax to initialize an array is incorrect :

```
---->    locations = new[]{
            new Vector3(anchorPoint.x + 1, anchorPoint.y, anchorPoint.z),
            new Vector3(anchorPoint.x - 1, anchorPoint.y, anchorPoint.z),
            new Vector3(anchorPoint.x, anchorPoint.y + 1, anchorPoint.z),
            new Vector3(anchorPoint.x, anchorPoint.y - 1, anchorPoint.z),
            new Vector3(anchorPoint.x, anchorPoint.y, anchorPoint.z + 1),
            new Vector3(anchorPoint.x, anchorPoint.y, anchorPoint.z - 1)
        };
```

you have forgotten the new[] which indicates its an array